# Angular 4 Universal Lazy Loading Error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I have set up a new Angular CLI project to learn how to enable server-side rendering using Angular Universal.

I've set is up and everything is working great, but I decided to lazy-load a module called 'lazy'.

I did that, when using `ng serve` it works, but when Universal is running (with AOT), when I go to the lazy route and refresh the page I get this error, although I see the lazy component in the browser:

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined
ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadFactory (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\core\src\linker\system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts:67:1)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:5724:35)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\router\src\router_config_loader.ts:71:1)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:3402:52)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:1570:74)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\operator\mergeMap.ts:125:21)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\operator\mergeMap.ts:115:12)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\Subscriber.ts:95:12)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\observable\ScalarObservable.ts:51:18)
    at ScalarObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\Observable.ts:113:19)
    at resolvePromise (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:770:31)
    at resolvePromise (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:741:17)
    at C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:818:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:424:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\core\src\zone\ng_zone.ts:257:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:423:36)
    at Zone.runTask (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:191:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:584:35)
    at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:490:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
  rejection:
   { ReferenceError: System is not defined
       at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadFactory (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\core\src\linker\system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts:67:1)
       at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:5724:35)
       at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\router\src\router_config_loader.ts:71:1)
       at RouterConfigLoader.load (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:3402:52)
       at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:1570:74)
       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\operator\mergeMap.ts:125:21)
       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\operator\mergeMap.ts:115:12)
       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\Subscriber.ts:95:12)
       at ScalarObservable._subscribe (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\observable\ScalarObservable.ts:51:18)
       at ScalarObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\Observable.ts:113:19)
     __zone_symbol__currentTask:
      ZoneTask {
        _zone: [Object],
        runCount: 0,
        _zoneDelegates: null,
        _state: 'notScheduled',
        type: 'microTask',
        source: 'Promise.then',
        data: undefined,
        scheduleFn: undefined,
        cancelFn: null,
        callback: [Function],
        invoke: [Function] } },
  promise:
   ZoneAwarePromise {
     __zone_symbol__state: 0,
     __zone_symbol__value:
      { ReferenceError: System is not defined
          at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadFactory (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\core\src\linker\system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts:67:1)
          at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:5724:35)
          at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\packages\router\src\router_config_loader.ts:71:1)
          at RouterConfigLoader.load (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:3402:52)
          at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:1570:74)
          at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\operator\mergeMap.ts:125:21)
          at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\operator\mergeMap.ts:115:12)
          at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\Subscriber.ts:95:12)
          at ScalarObservable._subscribe (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\observable\ScalarObservable.ts:51:18)
          at ScalarObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\shachar\Desktop\universal\node_modules\rxjs\src\Observable.ts:113:19) __zone_symbol__currentTask: [Object] } },
  zone:
   Zone {
     _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
     _parent:
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '<root>',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     _name: 'angular',
     _zoneDelegate:
      ZoneDelegate {
        _taskCounts: [Object],
        zone: [Circular],
        _parentDelegate: [Object],
        _forkZS: null,
        _forkDlgt: null,
        _forkCurrZone: [Object],
        _interceptZS: null,
        _interceptDlgt: null,
        _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
        _invokeZS: [Object],
        _invokeDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
        _handleErrorZS: [Object],
        _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
        _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
        _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
        _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
        _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _hasTaskZS: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
        _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
  task:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: undefined,
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
```

And no, I am not using SystemJS at all.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LazyModule } from './lazy/lazy.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'universal' }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

lazy.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: LazyComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [LazyComponent]
})
export class LazyModule { }

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ServerModule,
    AppModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

server.ts: (express)

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as Express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory } = require('../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory');

const app = Express();

enableProdMode();

const PORT = 4000;

const template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('views', join(__dirname, '..', 'dist'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('*.*', Express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am glad the universal is working but it's bad to get this error message every refresh.

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with Angular AOT CLI lazy load with server side rendering. Server is not aware of "System" which is default loader of angular. So in that case one need to add angular2-template-loader'and 'angular2-router-loader' for template loading on server side via webpack configuration.

Comment: Will it work with @ngtools/webpack as well? For example use: ['@ngtools/webpack', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular-router-loader']

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading using the CLI's bundler is not currently supported, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering#caveats). It's planned for an upcoming release and is under active development, so just hang tight in the meantime.